# How to avoid multiple if let statements in Swift 2

Tags: swift, option-type

I am starting out with swift am trying to keep my code concise.

I have a custom `init` method

```
var title, initMainText, initBtnTitle: String?

...

init(title: String?, mainText: String?, buttonTitle: String?) {
   if let t = title {
      self.title = t
   }
   if let t = mainText {
      self.initMainText = t
   }
   if let t = buttonTitle {
      self.initBtnTitle = t
   }
   ...
}

...
```

Is there a more concise way to unwrap all those conditionals?

Comment: This question needs more detail.  There's not really a more concise way to write this exact same logic.  There are more concise ways of unwrapping multiple values, but none of them apply the exact same logic you've got here.

Comment: the answer below answers my question quite well. I wasn't aware that I could pass the optional value without doing a check. No reason for a down vote. ;)

Comment: The downvote is for asking a vague question.

Comment: There is no more detail needed. The method has optional parameters and I was under the impression I need to unwrap them. But the option of assigning them to other optional values is just as good. And I will then `guard` against `nil` when they are "used".

Comment: That `self.title` is an optional is a guess because your vague question doesn't include the declaration of the variable.  That someone made guesses at a good answer for your question does not make your question good.

Comment: granted - I will add the variable declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions:

- `guard`
- multiple `let`/`var` inside the same `if`
- params with default values
- ternary conditional operator
- Nil Coalescing Operator
- Don't accept optional params in the `init` (as suggested by *nhgrif*)

Looking at your example it seems that

- `self.title`
- `self.initMainText`
- `self.initBtnTitle`

are optionals so you could simply write:

```
init(title: String?, mainText: String?, buttonTitle: String?) {
   self.title = title
   self.initMainText = mainText
   self.initBtnTitle = buttonTitle
   ...
}
```

Comment: Only right answer.  You missed one solution though (which would be my first recommendation): don't accept optionals.  Change the signature to `init(title: String, mainText: String, buttonTitle: String)`

Comment: As @nhgrif was fond of pointing out, this isn't the same logic.  You are overwriting a potential default value with `nil` when `nil`s are sent to the initializer.

Comment: Look how the properties are defined in the original question. They don't have a default value so there is nothing to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different logic that yours.  If you'd like to assign a default value to the properties when `nil` is sent into the initializer, then this would be a good place for the *nil coalescing operator*:

```
init(title: String?, mainText: String?, buttonTitle: String?) {
   self.title = title ?? ""
   self.initMainText = mainText ?? ""
   self.initBtnTitle = buttonTitle ?? ""
   ...
}
```

Now that it is clear that your properties are optionals, the following has the same logic as yours: it will change the value of the property if the new value is not `nil`:

```
class Foo {
    var title: String? = "possible default value"
    var initMainText: String? = "possible default value"
    var initBtnTitle: String? = "possible default value"

    init(title: String?, mainText: String?, buttonTitle: String?) {
        self.title = title ?? self.title
        self.initMainText = mainText ?? self.initMainText
        self.initBtnTitle = buttonTitle ?? self.initBtnTitle
    }
}
```

Comment: This is different logic.  Realistically, you want `self.title = title ?? self.title`

Comment: This is an initializer, so self.title has no value yet.

Comment: @vacawama: Actually `self.title` could already have a value if declared with a default value.

Comment: @vacawama: 1) With my comment I mean that with `self.title = title ?? ""` you are losing the default value of `self.title`. 2) The code actually works: `class Bob {
 var title = "Bob"
 init(name: String?) {
  self.title = title ?? self.title
 }
}`

Comment: I see what you're saying.  In that case I would suggest `class Bob { var title init(name: String?) { self.title = title ?? "Bob" }`.  Doing it your way has merit though if you have several initializers.

Comment: Yes, mine was only an example to show you that it does compile :-) Yes placing the default value into the declaration of the property is a good practice because if you have multiple initializers you are not repeating the default value.

Comment: Finally please let me note that using an `empty String` is not a good way to represent the absence of value in Swift. `nil` is usually the right way represent the `no value` concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in single statement with comma seprated `if` or `guard`. But in this case if `title` and `mainText` should be non nil. **It is different logic but this is one way to define multiple condition in single line.** If you want other wise than you should refer @vacawama answer

```
var title: String? = "title"
var mainText: String? = "maintest"

if let title = title, mainText = mainText {
    self.initMainText = title
    self.initBtnTitle = mainText
}
```

Comment: This is a different logic, infact if only `title` (or `mainText`) is populated then the `if` body is not executed.